# z-index woes - z-index not working with combination of relative and absolute divs

Tags: html, css, z-index

having some trouble with my z-indexing.

in short I have an absolute div underneath a relative div called container.  in the container I have three divs, left center and right all absolute positioned.

I want the absolute div at the bottom ( a white line ) to appear over the top of center div but behind left and right div ( all of which are in the container div )

Now Z-index does one of two things, it either puts the white line under all three of the main divs or in front of them all.  there is no middle ground.

http://dev1.peeknpoke.co.uk for the site and reference material

thanks for any help,

still fixing holes in my knowledge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove #whiteline element

2) Change the css property of the #blackbar element like this:

```
background:black url("/img/line.png") repeat-x scroll 0 40px;
```

3) You should edit that `logobackground.png` image by cutting it in half for not appearing in front of the line..

Comment: Yeah I have actually got a cut version of the pic as I knew this would fix it even just as it is but that wasn't really such a concern I mostly wanted to know why it wasn't working because its useful to know for future designs.  I hadn't really thought of using the pic on the background! always handy to streamline code.

Comment: The problem at your code was that you tried to use z-index even if the element was positioned in different container. That z-index is applied in different contexts. So you can apply z-index to elements in the same container at the same level for position them one behind the other

Comment: so basically what i am trying to do, in the current layout is impossible? :) that's perfect thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your all code is wrong. The z-index will work if you put higher z-index on `.wrapper` than `.whiteline`. But because the html is wrong it will break another part of your site.

Learn more about z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, I have however looked at most resources for z-index and generally understand it.  I was hoping one of you guys might point out the specific issue and be kind enough to explain it to me.